# Nullrouting a KVM guest from the node

Tags: linux, virtualization, iptables, kvm-virtualization

I have a "development" KVM server here at the office, setup in a bridged networking setup with a few KVM guests running on it. For each KVM guest a virtual interface is created on the node with the name `kvm[id].0` e.g. `kvm126.0` when the guest boots. 
Yesterday I was playing around and wanted to see how I could nullroute a KVM guest in case I needed to.

So I tried `route add ip_address reject` which had no effect, as no effect had `route add ip_address gw 127.0.0.1 lo` or `ip route add blackhole ip_address/32`.
Since it's a bridged network setup, I get why the above didn't work.

Next try was with iptables; I tried

```
iptables -A INPUT -s ip_address -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -s ip_address -j DROP
```

which did the trick, I couldn't ping the KVM guest anymore.

Now the thing is that if I were a malicious user, I would start trying other neighboring IPs until I find one that doesn't conflict with another guest and statically assign it to my VPS.

So what I would like to know is, if there's a way to block traffic from this guest's particular interface, no matter what IP he has managed to configure his guest machine with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could connect to the monitor and shut down the link:

```
(qemu) set_link tap.0 down
```

The command `info network` will list the network interfaces.

Note that you must detach the monitor with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Using `q` or `quit` wourld terminate the VM.

Comment: I'm using virsh instead of qemu, but your answer led me to a command line list, where I found the `virsh detach-interface` command, that does exactly what I need :) So, thanks!